# Manually starting hyperledger peers using docker images

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger

The [hyperledger project](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) has a built-in docker image definition for running peer nodes. Given the vagrant focused development environment documentation, it's not immediately obvious that you can set up your own chain network using docker-compose.

To do that, first build the docker image by running this test (this test step is entirely dedicated to building the image):

```
go test github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/container -run=BuildImage_Peer
```

Once the image is built, use docker-compose to launch the peer nodes. This folder has some pre-built yaml files for docker-compose:

```
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bddtests
```

Use the following command to launch 3 peers (for instance):

```
 docker-compose -f docker-compose-3.yml up --force-recreate -d
```

After the container instances are up, use `docker inspect` to get the IP addresses and use port `5000` to call the REST APIs (refer to the documentation for REST API spec).

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: no question. just documenting what I discovered from asking colleagues (which could have been asked here in the first place) for the benefit of the nascent hyperledger community

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not a question rather its just a discovery that OP wanted to share with the community

Comment: you should write a blog post on medium.com, if u do that, please share the link here!

Comment: this is a very interesting problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in the hyperledger/fabric github repository under the [./bddtests](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/bddtests)  and [./consensus/docker-compose-files](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/consensus/docker-compose-files) directories for examples on how to setup peer networks of 3, 4 or 5 nodes.

Remember to expose port 5000 for one of the validating peers so that you can use the REST api to interact with the peer node.

Answer (score 3):

Now that the Hyperledger Fabric project has published its [inaugural release](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/wiki/Fabric-Releases) (v0.5-developer-preview), we have begun publishing official Hyperledger docker images for the [fabric-baseimage](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage/), [fabric-peer](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-peer/) and [fabric-membersrvc](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc/).

These images can be deployed, as noted by other respondents, using docker-compose. As noted above in the response by @tuand, the fabric/bddtests are a good source of compose files that could be repurposed.

Note that if running on a Mac or Windows using Docker for Mac(beta) that you'll need to use port mapping to expose ports for a peer, as Docker for Mac does not support routing IP traffic to and from containers. Container linking works as expected. Hence, you will either need to map different ports for each of the peers, or only expose a single peer instance.

The following compose file will start a single peer node on a Mac using Docker for Mac. Simply run `docker-compose up`:

```
vp:
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
ports:
- "5000:5000"
environment:
- CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
- CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:2375
- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
command: peer node start
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two github repositories that let you build docker images with hyperledger that you can run directly

https://github.com/joequant/hyperledger

and

https://github.com/yeasy/docker-hyperledger-peer

Under yeasy there are some repositories that contain fabric deploy scripts.